# unable to parse the json file in python with multiple json objects

Tags: python, json, api

I want to parse a json file which contains multiple json root elements in python but I am getting this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 325 column 2 (char 11121) multiple json objects
```

Here is the code I am trying:

```
data_json= json.load(open("C:/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/starting/newfile.json", 'r'))
```

Here is the sample how json is in the file:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "result": {
    "data": {
      "totalIncidents": 203.0,
      "incidentItems": [
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest4 Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657910,
          "violatorId": "5",
          "incidentId": "108662",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "LowMedium",
          "priority": "None",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Resource: HC_MWS1",
            "Threat Model: Low Cloud AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "666666666",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "Low_Medium",
          "url": "https://securityindex.com",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": true,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657862,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657742,
          "violatorId": "1",
          "incidentId": "108640",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "LowMedium",
          "priority": "None",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Threat Model: Low Email AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "888888888",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "Low_Medium",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108640",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657697,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest4 Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657576,
          "violatorId": "5",
          "incidentId": "108618",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "LowMedium",
          "priority": "None",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Resource: HC_MWS1",
            "Threat Model: Low Email AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "666666666",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "Low_Medium",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108618",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657529,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657413,
          "violatorId": "1",
          "incidentId": "108596",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Threat Model: Medium Email AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "888888888",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108596",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657366,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest4 Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657239,
          "violatorId": "5",
          "incidentId": "108574",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Resource: HC_MWS1",
            "Threat Model: Medium Email AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "666666666",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108574",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657190,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest4 Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657050,
          "violatorId": "5",
          "incidentId": "108552",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Resource: HC_MWS1",
            "Threat Model: Medium Cloud AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "666666666",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108552",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657009,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest4 Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203656773,
          "violatorId": "5",
          "incidentId": "108530",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Resource: HC_MWS1",
            "Threat Model: Medium Cloud AND PRI_SB"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "666666666",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108530",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": true,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203656733,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203656624,
          "violatorId": "1",
          "incidentId": "108508",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Threat Model: Medium USB AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "888888888",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108508",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203656579,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203656478,
          "violatorId": "1",
          "incidentId": "108486",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Threat Model: WeTransfer Blocked violations"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "888888888",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108486",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203656436,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203656327,
          "violatorId": "1",
          "incidentId": "108464",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Threat Model: Medium CDDVD AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "888888888",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108464",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203656282,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  "status": "OK",
  "result": {
    "data": {
      "totalIncidents": 203.0,
      "incidentItems": [
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest4 Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657910,
          "violatorId": "5",
          "incidentId": "108662",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "LowMedium",
          "priority": "None",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Resource: HC_MWS1",
            "Threat Model: Low Cloud AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "666666666",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "Low_Medium",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108662",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": true,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657862,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657742,
          "violatorId": "1",
          "incidentId": "108640",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "LowMedium",
          "priority": "None",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Threat Model: Low Email AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "888888888",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "Low_Medium",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108640",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657697,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest4 Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657576,
          "violatorId": "5",
          "incidentId": "108618",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "LowMedium",
          "priority": "None",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Resource: HC_MWS1",
            "Threat Model: Low Email AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "666666666",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "Low_Medium",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108618",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657529,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657413,
          "violatorId": "1",
          "incidentId": "108596",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Threat Model: Medium Email AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "888888888",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108596",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657366,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest4 Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657239,
          "violatorId": "5",
          "incidentId": "108574",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Resource: HC_MWS1",
            "Threat Model: Medium Email AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "666666666",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108574",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657190,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest4 Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203657050,
          "violatorId": "5",
          "incidentId": "108552",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Resource: HC_MWS1",
            "Threat Model: Medium Cloud AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "666666666",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108552",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203657009,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest4 Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203656773,
          "violatorId": "5",
          "incidentId": "108530",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Resource: HC_MWS1",
            "Threat Model: Medium Cloud AND PRI_SB"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "666666666",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108530",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": true,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203656733,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203656624,
          "violatorId": "1",
          "incidentId": "108508",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Threat Model: Medium USB AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "888888888",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108508",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203656579,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203656478,
          "violatorId": "1",
          "incidentId": "108486",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Threat Model: WeTransfer Blocked violations"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "888888888",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108486",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203656436,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        },
        {
          "violatorText": "UEBATest Account",
          "lastUpdateDate": 1615203656327,
          "violatorId": "1",
          "incidentId": "108464",
          "incidentStatus": "Open",
          "riskscore": 0.0,
          "assignedGroup": "SecOps",
          "priority": "High",
          "reason": [
            "Number Of Threat: 1",
            "Threat Model: Medium CDDVD AND PRI"
          ],
          "violatorSubText": "888888888",
          "entity": "Users",
          "workflowName": "IDP",
          "url": "https://securityindex.comSnypr/configurableDashboards/view?\u0026type\u003dincident\u0026id\u003d108464",
          "isWhitelisted": false,
          "watchlisted": false,
          "tenantInfo": {
            "tenantid": 1,
            "tenantname": "DEV",
            "tenantcolor": "#000000",
            "tenantshortcode": "SE"
          },
          "statusCompleted": false,
          "sandBoxPolicy": false,
          "parentCaseId": "",
          "casecreatetime": 1615203656282,
          "bulkactionallowed": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you open the json in an editor with line numbering, and tell us what's happening at line 325? And does your json have [ ] surrounding your objects?

Comment: at line number 325 the first json object ends with a comma"," following  and at line number 326 the other json object begins

Comment: Does the object before the comma have the same number of { as }? (You can copy-paste it into an online json editor to check. In fact, try pasting in the whole file.)

Comment: saved a sample file which has two json elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround your json objects with a `[` at the start of the file and a `]` at the end to make it an array of json objects, so your code knows to look for more than one.

Comment: Thank you very much